# Android: How to change Recyclerview's items properties from MainActivity

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have Recyclerview with Textview and Checkbox. Each item can be hidden or shown. In MainActivity, at run I show only items which are not hidden. But in menu I have an option called - show hidden items. at click I have t oshow also hidden Items, but with gray color. 
HOw can I do it? how to reach Recyclerview's single item's properties from MainActivity ?

Here is my code:

RVAdapter

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.DataHolder> {

    static String LOG = "RV_LOG";
    ArrayList<DataObject> myData;
    MainActivity mainActivity;
    public static MyClickListener myClickListener;

    public class DataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
        TextView text;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        private int position;
        public DataHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        }

        public void setPosition(int value) {
            this.position = value;
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickListener.onItemClick(position, v);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            mainActivity.onItemClick(position, buttonView, isChecked);

        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }

    public RVAdapter(ArrayList<DataObject> myData, MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.myData = myData;
        this.mainActivity=mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public DataHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_single_item, parent, false);

        return new DataHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DataHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.text.setText(myData.get(position).getText());
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(myData.get(position).getCheck());
        if (myData.get(position).getHidden()) {
            holder.text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#d6d6c2"));
            holder.text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.setPosition(position);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public void addItem(DataObject object, int index) {
        myData.add(index, object);
        notifyItemInserted(index);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int index) {
        myData.remove(index);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myData.size();
    }

    public interface MyClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager;


    private ArrayList<DataObject> data;
    String TAG = "MA Tag";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        data = new ArrayList<DataObject>();
        boolean hidden = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            DataObject object = new DataObject("Item No " + (i + 1), false, hidden);
            data.add(i, object);
            hidden = !hidden;
        }

        myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        adapter = new RVAdapter(data, this);
        myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

    }

    public void onItemClick(int position, View view, boolean isChecked) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.text:
                Log.d(TAG, "item is clicked");
                break;

            case R.id.checkbox:
                data.get(position).setCheck(isChecked);
                Log.d(TAG, position + " is " + data.get(position).getCheck() + ":" + isChecked);
                if (isChecked) {
                    data.get(position).setCheck(true);
               } else {
                    data.get(position).setCheck(false);
                    Log.d(TAG, position + " is " + data.get(position).getCheck());

                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete:

               for(int i = data.size()-1; i >=0; i--){
                   if(data.get(i).getCheck())
                        ((RVAdapter) myRecyclerView.getAdapter()).deleteItem(data.indexOf(data.get(i)));
                   }

                break;
            case R.id.show:
                Log.d(TAG, "Show");
                for(int i = 0; i <data.size(); i++){
                    if(data.get(i).getHidden()){
                        Log.d(TAG, data.get(i).getText());
                        data.get(i).setHidden(false);
                    }
                }

                break;

        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.layout_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

*UPDATE:*

now my RVAdapter looks so:

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.DataHolder> {

    static String LOG = "RV_LOG";
    ArrayList<DataObject> myData;
    MainActivity mainActivity;

    public class DataHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,
            CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
        TextView text;
        CheckBox checkBox;
        private int position;
        public DataHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            text.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }

        public void setPosition(int value) {
            this.position = value;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mainActivity.onItemClick(position, v, true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mainActivity.onItemClick(position, buttonView, isChecked);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            mainActivity.onLongClick(position);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public RVAdapter(ArrayList<DataObject> myData, MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.myData = myData;
        this.mainActivity=mainActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public DataHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_single_item, parent, false);

        return new DataHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final DataHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.text.setText(myData.get(position).getText());
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(myData.get(position).getCheck());
        if (myData.get(position).getHidden()) {
            holder.text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if(myData.get(position).getWasHidden()){
            holder.text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
        }
        holder.setPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public void deleteItem(int index) {
        myData.remove(index);
        notifyItemRemoved(index);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(index, myData.size());
    }

    public void hideItem(int position){
        myData.get(position).setHidden(true);

    }

    public void showItem(int position){
        myData.get(position).setHidden(false);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myData.size();
    }
}
```

in my Activity I call showItem() method.

```
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.delete:
               for(int i = data.size()-1; i >=0; i--){
                   if(data.get(i).getCheck())
                        ((RVAdapter) myRecyclerView.getAdapter()).deleteItem(data.indexOf(data.get(i)));
                   }
                break;
            case R.id.show:
                for(int i = 0; i< data.size(); i++) {
                    if(data.get(i).getHidden())
                    ((RVAdapter) myRecyclerView.getAdapter()).showItem(i);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

It works a bit wrong: At run every second item is shown(correct, cause every second is not hidden). When I tap on Show, hidden items appear, but first two shown items disappear. when I tap on Show again, they appear. what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method inside the adapter to show the hidden items. Since you have the adapter object inside your Main Activity you can easily call that method from inside your Main Activity. After calling that method, call notifyDataSetChanged() method from your MainActivity itself. notifyDataSetChanged() method will be called by the adapter object.

Comment: well, it worked, but I have an issue here:

` public void showHiddenItems(){
        for(int i = 0; i < myData.size(); i++){
            if(myData.get(i).getHidden()){
                myData.get(i).setHidden(false);

            }
        }
    } `

and in itemclick function:

` case R.id.show:
                ((RVAdapter) myRecyclerView.getAdapter()).showHiddenItems();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break; `

I click on Show hidden items, it doesn't show first two hidden items. I click on it again, and it shows all. (every second item is hidden)

Comment: Please update your adapter code with your latest code. Then I'll be able to help you with this bug.

Comment: Your code looks correct. Do you still get  that bug ?